# как вытащить из метода массив, чтобы использовать его в другом методе?

Tags: javascript, массивы, классы, return

нужно вытащить результат работы первого метода, и отправить его во второй, этот массив с юзерами. Думаю, как-то нужно использовать this, и я пробовал, но ничего не получается...

```
class OwnerAuto {
    constructor(name, lastName, phone, brandAuto, cool) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.brandAuto = brandAuto;
        this.cool = cool;
    }
    formatNewArr(){//ввод ограниченного кол-ва владельцев в массив
        let arr = [];
        let num = +prompt('количество человек:');
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++){
            arr[i] = new OwnerAuto(
                prompt('имя:'),
                prompt('фамилия:'),
                +prompt('телефон:'),
                prompt('марка машины:'),
                confirm('вы крутой?'))
        }
        return arr;
    }
    goodView(){
        let count = 1;
        for(let i of arr){
            console.log(`
            |Пациент №${count++}
            |Имя: ${i.name}
            |Фамилия: ${i.lastName}
            |Телефон: ${i.phone}
            |Марка машины: ${i.brandAuto}
            |Крутость: ${i.cool}
            ------------------------------
            `)
        }
    }
}

let newOwnerAuto = new OwnerAuto();
console.log(newOwnerAuto.formatNewArr());
console.log(newOwnerAuto.arr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не смотря на всё некорректность кода, тем не менее дам ответ как можно сделать....но в итоге это всё неправильно по разным причинам (я не про своё решение, а про код самого автора). Количество свойств намеренно уменьшил, чтобы не раздувать код

```js
class OwnerAuto {
    constructor(name = 'defaultName', lastName = 'defaulLastName') {
        this.users = [];   
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    formatNewArr(){//ввод ограниченного кол-ва владельцев в массив        
        let num = +prompt('количество человек:');
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++){
            this.users.push(new OwnerAuto(
                    prompt('имя:'),
                    prompt('фамилия:')               
                )
            );
        }
    }
    goodView(){
        let count = 1;        
        for(let i of this.users){
            console.log(`
            |Пациент №${count++}
            |Имя: ${i.name}
            |Фамилия: ${i.lastName}
            ------------------------------
            `)
        }
    }
}

let newOwnerAuto = new OwnerAuto();
newOwnerAuto.formatNewArr();
newOwnerAuto.goodView();
```

Comment: Интересно, спасибо. Был бы рад  услышать, как правильно было бы сделать. Задание было таким - "Выбрать предметную область для базы данных и предложить структуру объектов для описания отдельных записей базы данных. Выбранная структура должна иметь не менее пяти свойств двух и более типов. Для выбранной базы данных написать следующие функции: 
1. Функцию формирования массива объектов, значения свойств которых вводятся с клавиатуры. При вводе объектов можно реализовать один из следующих механизмов: 
1.ввод заранее заданного количества объектов;
2.Функцию просмотра содержимого массива объектов.

Comment: @GansLiber ну как минимум класс, хранящий в себе информацию о своих данных (OwnerAuto) и класс. который ведёт учёт "пациентов" должны быть разными. Второй класс, должен содарежать в себе массив объектов первого класса (типа). А сейчас получается какой-то замкнутый круг., какой-то бог авто содержит в себе знания о других..... должно быть условно так (сейчас не про код который выше) Класс КарточкаПациента и Класс Больница. Больница регистрирует пациентов и хранит карточки с ними

Answer (score 1):

После вызова `formatNewArr()` будет вызвана `goodView()`

```js
class OwnerAuto {
    constructor(name, lastName, phone, brandAuto, cool) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.brandAuto = brandAuto;
        this.cool = cool;
        this.arr = []
    }
    formatNewArr(){//ввод ограниченного кол-ва владельцев в массив
        let num = +prompt('количество человек:');
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++){
             this.arr[i] = new OwnerAuto(
                prompt('имя:'),
                prompt('фамилия:'),
                +prompt('телефон:'),
                prompt('марка машины:'),
                confirm('вы крутой?'))
        }
        this.goodView()
        return this.arr;
    }
    goodView(){
        let count = 1;
        for(let i of this.arr){
            console.log(`
            |Пациент №${count++}
            |Имя: ${i.name}
            |Фамилия: ${i.lastName}
            |Телефон: ${i.phone}
            |Марка машины: ${i.brandAuto}
            |Крутость: ${i.cool}
            ------------------------------
            `)
        }
    }
}

let newOwnerAuto = new OwnerAuto();
console.log(newOwnerAuto.formatNewArr());
console.log(newOwnerAuto.arr);
```